# Set schemaLocation on XML JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb

I need to add schemaLocation Property that is nested on another object,

I have a class...

```
...
@XmlRootElement(name = "Comp")
public class Comp {
...
```

I marshall objects of this class setting **Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION** and it works great, but now there is another class that has a property like this...

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TSAT")
public class TSAT {
...
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
     protected Object any;
...
```

and then I set that property with an instance of Comp, setting the property **Marshaller.JAXB_SCHEMA_LOCATION** do adds the **schemaLocation** attribute but for the **TSAT element** and I want it for the **Comp element**.

I tried marshalling the Comp element and then setting it on the any property, then marshalling TSAT, but I got Comp wrapped inside an  tag.

**what I want:**

```
<TSAT>
   <Comp schemaLocation="uri">
   ...
   </Comp>
</TSAT>
```

**what I get:**

```
<TSAT schemaLocation="uri">
   <Comp>
   ...
   </Comp>
</TSAT>
```

**or**

```
<TSAT>
   <any>
   &amp;lt;Comp schemaLocation="uri"&amp;gt;
   ...
   &amp;lt;/Comp&amp;gt;
   </any>
</TSAT>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using different marshallers? i.e. one marshaller that marshals Comp object. This marshaller has xmlschema property. Marshal JAXBElement in a DOMResult. And set the element from DOMResult in Tsat.any object and then marshal Tsat using another marshaller. I don't guarantee that it will work, but worth trying.

Comment: Ask for extra information in a comment, then answer when you have that information.  Otherwise, this is not useful.